# Splunk charts series with multiple sections

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

How to create a chart that represents a series in a single bar with multiple sections? What type of chart should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

To create a chart you'll need some statistics.  Use the `stats` command for that.  Something like `| stats count by foo`.  Tell us more about your use case and data so we can be more specific.

I think you're thinking of a Stacked Bar (or Column) chart.  After you've run your search, click on the Visualization tab then select either Bar (horizontal) or Column (vertical) chart.  Click on Format and select the middle Stack Mode to get a stacked chart.